# Block ports expect one IP

Tags: windows

I need to block port 80 and 443 on the server (SBS 2011) and allow only one IP or user PC, there are http and https rules already on the inbound. I have tried under properties of http and under general tab I select "allow connection if secure" and under computers tab I select to add a computer. I have tried to tick "authorized computers" and "exceptions" and adding computers but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Create the rule in the firewall that way please. It work on my side.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, may be it's because I didn't mask my ip address